# How to view a daemon's output in a session on Raspbian/Debian?

Tags: debian, raspbian, output, session

Okay I'm pretty new to Linux and I have setup a Raspberry Pi 2 with Raspbian and it's running a bunch of things for tracking aircraft as well as a receiver (RTL-SDR). It's all working great and I'm using [Dump1090](https://github.com/MalcolmRobb/dump1090) for decoding/demodulating the signal.

Dump1090 has an --interactive mode that displays a row/column layout in the terminal when started normally (not as a daemon) which is the signal the receiver is picking up from the plane. I have Dump1090 starting as a daemon now and I'd like to see the --interactive output when I start a session with a command or something. The daemon is being started with --interactive already.

Obviously when I SSH in I don't see this output and I'd like to know if there's a way I can sort of "alt tab" to view its output. Is this not possible? Do I need to install something in particular on the OS in order to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I went with terdon's comment and using the advice from garethTheRed. Outputting to a file and accessing the file to see output works in the terminal fine so I will go with that. I also use this in conjunction with the web server that shares the data. I will mark garethTheRed's answer as accepted as it's the only one for coherency sake while keeping my explanation of also using terdon's advice which is a solution to my problem. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Could you [edit] and clarify exactly how this is being launched? The simplest way is to redirect the error output to a file by adding `2> /path/to/file` at the end of the command used to launch it. You should also check the output of `dmesg` and the files in `/var/log` in case anything is being printed there.

Comment: It's through a custom shell script. Any way though I'm outputting it to a file and that's working for me, thanks for that suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't got `dump1090` or a receiver to confirm any of this. But if you read further down in that github page you've linked you'll see that if you run:

```
./dump1090 --interactive --net
```

it will start it's built-in web server.

You can then connect to the Raspberry Pi's port `8080` with your web browser by entering it's IP address and port in the browser's address bar:

```
http://<IP address of Rasberry Pi>:8080/
```

(don't forget that colon `:` before the `8080`)

Your browser should show your live traffic.

Comment: Yeah been using this but wanted to know if there's a way to see the output in the terminal but terdon's comment I went with to output it to a log. That's working and I can access the log. Thanks for the reply, I'm using this web access as well (it's the same data).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to capture such output is to redirect standard error to a file. In the shell, this is done with `2> file`. So, if your daemon is normally launched like this:

```
dump1090 --interactive
```

Change that to

```
dump1090 --interactive 2> /tmp/dumplog
```

That will save its output to the file `/tmp/dumplog`. To be on the safe side, you can redirect both standard error and standard output (since I don't know which of the two your program is writing to):

```
dump1090 --interactive > /tmp/dumplog 2>&1
```